# Website for generating random names and addresses

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a website which can generate random (fake) names & addresses ?

If it can also provide random fake Credit Cards, SSN that would be great, as is the capability to generate a whole set of data which I can download in various formats

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Fake Name Generator](http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/) is capable of creating entire fake identities, including nationality, phone numbers, credit card numbers, addresses, biometric info like height and weight and even blood type, and more.

Perhaps the best feature is the ability to [download entire datasets](http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/order.php) of fake identities. This allows you to set which demographics you want included, how many entries you need, and a format to export in. The site will generate the identities for you, then email you when they are ready, with a link to download a zip file containing all of the entries. I've used this before for populating identity management software with data for testing, and it works great. Pretty much any personal info your database might need to hold will be available, and can easily be imported as you can download a csv, text, or even SQL file with the data.

Comment: It also generates a "UPS Tracking Number"? :P